# What word describes this verbal slip-up?

Tags: speech, errors

I just overheard my officemate, while she was on a conference call, say "My muke was mited", and I've said before "We need some more print for the inker".

These aren't quite [spoonerisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism), as far as I can see. Is there another word which describes this type of speech error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Metathesis](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/metathesis)**

> 1. Linguistics Transposition within a word of letters, sounds, or syllables, as in the change from Old English brid to modern English bird or in the confusion of modren for modern.

Comment: Or _wops_ for _wasp_, _ax_ for _ask_, _grain_ for _corn_, and many others.  Automnemonic: _metathesis_ = _methatesis_.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Dr. Spooner did make errors of this kind, not just transposing initial letters. If you scroll down the Wikipedia article you find that someone coined the terms 'kniferisms and forkerisms' for different kinds of metathesis, but some consider all kinds to be Spoonerisms.

Comment: The slips cited by the OP are better termed spoonerisms than metathesis, seeing that they involve swapping parts of *different words*, whereas metathesis, as WDO pointed out, refers to a swap within a word.

Comment: In ordinary speech, swapping of various sorts extends over speech groups, which can span whole sentences. Most of the time, people don't speak in sentences but in phrases, which are effectively treated as if they were one word.